# How is the view in Google Play Music Artists called?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I wondered how that specific image view in the artist section of the Google Play Music app is called. When clicking on an artist I get an image of the artist at the top and a ListView right below. When scrolling down the "ImageView" doesn't behave like a normal view, it scrolls up slower than the views below it.

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

As you might see, the imageview scrolled less up than the container below of it (small arrow ImageView, long arrow container)

Does anybody know how that view ist called?

**Edit**:

I was making some research and found following class:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/ContactsCommon/+/master/src/com/android/contacts/common/widget/ProportionalLayout.java

Is it possible that that's the same view I am searching for? However, following is documented in that class:

```
height := width * factor
```

So i guess that's what i am searching for, could somebody maybe take a look at it?

Comment: have you put artist image in header view ?

Comment: What do you mean with header view?

Comment: header view mean you can add header view list view so your header view part also scroll with list view and i think you don't know about header and footer to list View.

Comment: I don't think it's a header because it doesn't stay at the top: it scrolls up, but slower than the listview

Comment: when you add header or footer in list view it also scroll up.

Comment: But not in that specific way the artist cover does it.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some research I found what I've searched for: The View is called "ParallaxScrollView".